# Can we save Sales Order document on Soline- Inventory field updated event? if yes please guide me how to do

Tags: acumatica

Can we save the Sales Order document on Soline- Inventory field updated event? if yes please guide me on how to do this. I wish to close the Sales order on the selection of Inventory in SOLine in field updated event.

Comment: Sounds possible with a customization, you could call the Close action in the FieldUdpated event. It is considered bad practice both technically and logically to do so however. Software wasn't designed to close in that context and it would also surprise user to have a close action triggered by changing the value of a field.

Comment: The rule the platform tries to enforce is that Actions are triggered by button press or menu item click.